# how to access mesos http endpoints to fetch cluster information

Tags: curl, mesos

I have a local mesos setup (playa mesos) which is running in my local system. I have a requirement where i need to analyse the resource offering from different slaves and also need to get scheduling information from mesos  cluster nodes (master and slaves).

I am trying to using curl for hitting the HTTP endpoints as mentioned in the mesos documentation and try to get the information back.

```
 curl --no-buffer -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"type":"SUBSCRIBE","subscribe":{"framework_info":{"user":"root","name":"democurl"}}}' http://<ip address>:5050/master/api/v1/scheduler
```

which is returning the offerings from different slaves.
Now there are many HTTP endpoints related to scheduling, job execution etc which are not working. When I am trying to access them with curl it's simply not working and not returning any json data back.

I need help to make mesos http end points woking for all available resurces. I am trying to follow mesos documentation but no luck yet.It will be great if some one can post a sample curl command working. thanks

Comment: Which HTTP status code do you get (2xx, 3xx, 4xx, 5xx)? I just tried your curl command on a 0.28 Mesos cluster and it worked fine.

Comment: Hang on, these are two totally different questions now. IDK what the Java issue is w/o context but in case of /health this is the expected behavior—to return a 200, read the docs: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/health/

Comment: I am getting 4XX in general when trying from a java code. but "curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Accept:application/json" <ip address>:5050/master/health"; url is just not returning anything in the command prompt.

Comment: i am not trying with java for now. wanted to check all HTTP endpoints working with curl first. health, version, browse few of them are not returning anything, on the other hand few of them are working really well like snapshot, state-summery etc. I know my agents are healthy as i am not running any job into it for the time beeing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your curl command hitting the "/health" endpoint is working fine; you see nothing at the command-line because the 200 OK response has no body. To see the response headers as well, use the `-i` option with curl:

```
~/src/mesos/build|master⚡  curl -i --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -X GET localhost:5050/master/health
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 19:15:45 GMT
Content-Length: 0

~/src/mesos/build|master⚡  curl -i --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -X GET localhost:5050/master/state
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 19:16:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1504

{"version":"0.29.0","git_sha":"3b8ddc87e6fb7fe3c02147f30d9bacbc9d17bb14","git_branch":"refs\/heads\/master","build_date":"2016-03-28 13:59:44","build_time":1459198784.0,"build_user":"user","start_time":1459365180.7711,"elected_time":1459365180.78308,"id":"ed84d3b1-4153-4177-b96b-8a11be5d4959","pid":"master@127.0.0.1:5050","hostname":"localhost","activated_slaves":0.0,"deactivated_slaves":0.0,"leader":"master@127.0.0.1:5050","flags":{"allocation_interval":"1secs","allocator":"HierarchicalDRF","authenticate":"false","authenticate_http":"false","authenticate_slaves":"false","authenticators":"crammd5","authorizers":"local","framework_sorter":"drf","help":"false","hostname_lookup":"true","http_authenticators":"basic","initialize_driver_logging":"true","ip":"127.0.0.1","log_auto_initialize":"true","logbufsecs":"0","logging_level":"INFO","max_completed_frameworks":"50","max_completed_tasks_per_framework":"1000","max_slave_ping_timeouts":"5","port":"5050","quiet":"false","recovery_slave_removal_limit":"100%","registry":"replicated_log","registry_fetch_timeout":"1mins","registry_store_timeout":"20secs","registry_strict":"false","root_submissions":"true","slave_ping_timeout":"15secs","slave_reregister_timeout":"10mins","user_sorter":"drf","version":"false","webui_dir":"\/Users\/gmann\/src\/mesos\/build\/..\/src\/webui","work_dir":"\/Users\/gmann\/var\/mesos","zk_session_timeout":"10secs"},"slaves":[],"frameworks":[],"completed_frameworks":[],"orphan_tasks":[],"unregistered_frameworks":[]}%
```